# Create HTML table from kirby fields object

Tags: php, kirby

Below is my data and i want to generate html table. column_name is column Name(td) and row_data is td.

i have used kirby builder to generate this data structure.

I have loop on first table_data array and inside it i have loop on rows. but data gets printed in single column.

```
    Kirby\Cms\Field Object
(
    [table_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column_name] => Name
                    [rows] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [row_data] => Sunny
                                    [_key] => row
                                    [_uid] => row_1615486678901_4119
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [row_data] => ROhit
                                    [_key] => row
                                    [_uid] => row_1615486684935_4119
                                )

                        )

                    [_key] => main_menu
                    [_uid] => main_menu_1615486675536_647
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [column_name] => URL
                    [rows] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [row_data] => (link: www.google.com text: sunny)
                                    [_key] => row
                                    [_uid] => row_1615486840084_4304
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [row_data] => Open FD
                                    [_key] => row
                                    [_uid] => row_1615486873450_4304
                                )

                        )

                    [_key] => main_menu
                    [_uid] => main_menu_1615486830601_654
                )

        )

)
```